# How can i remove value from object

Tags: php, json, laravel

I am working in the PHP language.
The object is

> "[{"value":"test_1"},{"value":"test_2"}]"

and  I want

> ['test_1', 'test_2']

Here is my code...

```
foreach(json_decode($email) as $emails){
  $arr[]=$emails->value;
}

 $final = json_encode($arr);
```

The Output is

> "["test_1","test_2"]"

I am not satisfied with this output.
If anyone can help me please give an answer.

Comment: what version of PHP do you have? If greater than 5.5 you can use `array_column`

Comment: Please don't tag spam

Comment: Can you please explain what you're looking to achieve here? Do you want that data in a PHP array or in JSON? Because `['test_1', 'test_2']` is not valid JSON. `"["test_1","test_2"]"` is.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that You have the data of array of objects like

```
$array=[
   {
    "value":"value1"

  },
  {
   "value":"value2"
  }

 ]
```

simple use the function `pluck()` to retrieve data as you want .

```
$value_array=$array->pluck("value");
```

Your All keys need to be same to retrieve  all values

the `$value=["value1","value2"]`